# NodeJS. officegen

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm using [officegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen) to generate docx. To be be honest, I would like to have further information regarding to properties which might be used to config file more precise.
For example, according to documentation if I would like to describe a column of table I need to use smth like that

```
{
    val: "No.",
    opts: {
        cellColWidth: 4261,
        b:true,
        sz: '48',
        shd: {
            fill: "7F7F7F",
            themeFill: "text1",
            "themeFillTint": "80"
        },
        fontFamily: "Avenir Book"
    }
}
```

No doubts that there're some properties where I can predict their behavior. But for example, field `b` I don't know what is it responsible for.

Is there any better documentation about officegen?

Comment: Can you ask a specific question, please? Read [ask]